# update item total in database

Tags: java, database, jdbc

i'm having a little trouble with increasing the quantity of a product, when it is purchased, in a database.

I was told to look at this addProduct() method to see how I might go about writing the purchased(int quantityPurchased) method.

Here is that code:

```
public void addProduct(String desc, int qty, double price) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO ProductsDB (Product_Code, Description, Quantity, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            stat.setString(1, productCode);
            stat.setString(2, desc);
            stat.setInt(3, qty);
            stat.setDouble(4, price);
            stat.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I'm supposed to finish:

```
/**
 * Increases the quantity of product when we've purchased products to
 * replenish our supply.
 * 
 * @param number
 *            the count of products purchased.
 * @throws SQLException
 *             - on any database error
 */
public void purchased(int qtyPurchased) throws SQLException {
    // TODO: Update the ProductsDB table's quantity for this
    // object's product code.

}
```

Comment: Use the SQL UPDATE statement

Comment: learn some SQL and then attempt to solve the problem

Comment: The AddProduct() method basically gives you your answer...

Comment: ^expand on that

Comment: @sparkles please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you are updating the same table you need to know what product you are updating a quantity for. in that respect you need another parameter in your purchased() method so it will be like:
 `purchased(string productCode, int qtyPurchased)`.

After this you need to write another prepared statement that updates that table with the new value for the product.

Have a look at this:

```
        //Added another parameter for the method that takes the product code.
        public void purchased(string productCode, int qtyPurchased) throws SQLException 
        {
            try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) 
            {
                //Updated prepared statement to update a product row instead of inserting a new one using the specified product code.
                try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = ? WHERE Product_Code = ?") 
                {
                    //Update the values used in the prepared statement
                    stat.setInt(1, qtyPurchased);
                    stat.setString(2, productCode);

                    //Execute the statement (important)
                    stat.execute();
                }
            }
        }
```

Further reading here:

https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/

Comment: this works, however it just replaces the quantity to the amount purchased, i need it to add the amount purchased to the current quantity. for example, the current quantity is 50, i want to purchase 5, so it should display 55, but it just displays 5.

Comment: please see my comment

Comment: Okay, in that case you will need to do something similar to what I have given you above. The difference is that you will have only one parameter for a new method called GetProductQuantity that takes a productCode. After that update your prepared statement to "SELECT Quantity FROM ProductsDB", That will get you the total amount for the specified product. After this you just need to include the calculation in your purchased method. I cant do it all otherwise you wont learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works to get the `55` for `qtyPurchased`.
Just add this to the code above:

```
// Just add the + getQuantity() and you're good to go.
stat.setInt(1, qtyPurchased + getQuantity());
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13954836)

Comment: Sorry read my updated comment answer post above ^. The answer is there.